# Why woun't it hand over my object?

Tags: java, swing, oop, object, jframe

So i'm trying to hand over an object but it's telling me:

> The method `drawCommand(Launcher)` in the type Command is not
>   applicable for the arguments ()
>
> and
>
> `a` cannot be resolved to a variable.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Launcher extends JFrame {
    Launcher() {
        setSize(300, 400);
        setTitle("An Empty Frame");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private int width = 1000;
    private int hight = 750;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Launcher a = new Launcher();
        a.repaint();
        a.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        a.setTitle("Grafik");
        a.setSize(1000, 750);
        a.setVisible(true);
        a.operand();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics stift) {

        stift.drawString("A A A A A A A A A A ", 50, 50);
        stift.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i = i + 10)
            stift.drawLine(i, 0, i, hight);

        for (int i = 0; i < hight; i = i + 10)
            stift.drawLine(0, i, width, i);
    }

    public void operand() {

        System.out.println("Bitte geben sie etwas ein: ");
        Scanner eingabe1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String command = eingabe1.nextLine();
        // if(eingabe1!=null)
        // eingabe1.close();
        switch (command) {
        case "A":
            Command c = new Command();
            c.drawCommand(a);             //  here are the error messages
            System.out.println("draw fertig");
            // fenster.repaint();
            System.out.println("repaint fertig");
        }
    }
}
```

This is where a is coming from:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Command extends Commands {

    private String text = "";


    public Command() {
        super();
        text = "";
    }


    public Command(int width, int hight, int[] cornerLocation, String text) {
        super(width, hight, cornerLocation);
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void drawCommand(Launcher a) {

        System.out.println("Bitte geben sie den Text ein: ");
        Scanner eingabe2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        text = eingabe2.nextLine();
//      if(eingabe2!=null)
//          eingabe2.close();

    }

    public void paint(Graphics stift) {

        stift.setColor(Color.RED);
        stift.drawString("Hasebraten ",150,150);
        stift.drawRect(cornerLocation[0], cornerLocation[1], width, hight);
    }

}
```

Since I'm still new to JFrames and Graphics i get errors constantly, but i can't resolve this one

Answer (score 3):

In the code here where the error occurs, there is no variable `a` in scope and so the compiler is telling you this.

```
  switch (command) {
    case "A":
        Command c = new Command();
        c.drawCommand(a);             //  a is not in scope here so this does not compile..
        System.out.println("draw fertig");
        // fenster.repaint();
        System.out.println("repaint fertig");
    }
```

However, you do have a `Launcher` available at this time, because the class in question is a `Launcher` itself.

If you change the code to be:

```
c.drawCommand(this);
```

Then the `Launcher` object which is invoking the `drawCommand` method of the `Command` object, will pass itself to the `drawCommand` method as the `Launcher`.

This will meet the syntax expectations and move past this particular error.

I'm not entirely sure what you intend the code to do, and so I'm not sure if this will actually solve all of your problems, but it will certainly move you past that specific error.

Comment: (Just to calrify, I'm trying to write a program that draws Nassi–Shneiderman diagrams. By saying wich of 6 options: command, if, ifelse, switchcase, for, while and do while, you choos the layout of the rectangles it has to draw, then with another input you say what the rectangles should say. Sorry for bad spelling, not a native english speaker.)

Answer (score 0):

`Launcher a` is out of scope in the `operand()` function. You need to add a `Launcher` argument to `operand()` and pass the launcher.